Why are my JSON files not syncing? (Python Discord Bot)
So in this code, I have made a discord bot to get me registered so I can use the commands.
Current Code in register.py:
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import json
import os

class Register(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        
    @staticmethod
    def load_data(file):
        if not os.path.exists(file):
            return {}
        with open(file, "r") as f:
            try:
                data = json.load(f)
            except json.JSONDecodeError:
                data = {}
        return data
        
    @staticmethod
    def save_data(file, data):
        with open(file, "w") as f:
            json.dump(data, f)
      
    @commands.hybrid_command(aliases=["reg"], name="register", description="Register yourself to use our economy-related commands!")
    async def register(self, ctx):
        user_id = str(ctx.message.author.id)
        balance = self.load_data("data/balance.json")
        registered = self.load_data("data/registered.json")
        if user_id not in registered:
            registered[user_id] = True
            balance[user_id] = {
                "coins": 0,
                "gems": 0
            }
            self.save_data("data/registered.json", registered)
            self.save_data("data/balance.json", balance)
            register_embed = discord.Embed(
                title="Account Successfully Registered ✅", 
                description="You are now registered!", 
                color = discord.Color.green()
            )
            await ctx.send(embed=register_embed)
        else:
            registered_embed = discord.Embed(
                title="Account Already Registered", 
                description="You already have an account!", 
                color = discord.Color.red()
            )
            await ctx.send(embed=registered_embed)

async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(Register(bot))

Current Code in dig.py:
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import json
import os
import random
import asyncio
from helpers import checks
from discord.utils import format_dt
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

class Dig(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
    
    @staticmethod
    def load_data(file):
        if not os.path.exists(file):
            return {}
        with open(file, "r") as f:
            try:
                data = json.load(f)
            except json.JSONDecodeError:
                data = {}
        return data

    @staticmethod
    def save_data(file, data):
        with open(file, "w") as f:
            json.dump(data, f)

    @checks.has_registered()
    @commands.hybrid_command(aliases=["mine"], name="dig", description="Dig for coins in the earth!")
    @commands.cooldown(1, 10, commands.BucketType.user)
    async def dig(self, ctx):
        user_id = str(ctx.message.author.id)
        balance = self.load_data("data/balance.json")
        registered = self.load_data("data/registered.json")
        if user_id in registered:
            randomn = 0
            randomn = random.randint(1, 1024)
            coins_earned = 0
            if 1 <= randomn <= 2:
                coins_earned = 1000
            elif 3 <= randomn <= 7:
                coins_earned = 500
            elif 8 <= randomn <= 22:
                coins_earned = 200
            elif 23 <= randomn <= 52:
                coins_earned = 100
            elif 53 <= randomn <= 98:
                coins_earned = 95
            elif 99 <= randomn <= 145:
                coins_earned = 90
            elif 146 <= randomn <= 193:
                coins_earned = 85
            elif 194 <= randomn <= 242:
                coins_earned = 80
            elif 243 <= randomn <= 292:
                coins_earned = 75
            elif 293 <= randomn <= 343:
                coins_earned = 70
            elif 344 <= randomn <= 395:
                coins_earned = 65
            elif 396 <= randomn <= 448:
                coins_earned = 60
            elif 449 <= randomn <= 502:
                coins_earned = 55
            elif 503 <= randomn <= 556:
                coins_earned = 50
            elif 557 <= randomn <= 611:
                coins_earned = 45
            elif 612 <= randomn <= 667:
                coins_earned = 40
            elif 668 <= randomn <= 724:
                coins_earned = 35
            elif 725 <= randomn <= 782:
                coins_earned = 30
            elif 783 <= randomn <= 841:
                coins_earned = 25
            elif 842 <= randomn <= 901:
                coins_earned = 20
            elif 902 <= randomn <= 962:
                coins_earned = 15
            elif 963 <= randomn <= 1024:
                coins_earned = 10
            gem = 0
            gem = random.randint(1,10)
            coins = balance[user_id].get("coins")
            coins += coins_earned
            balance[user_id]["coins"] = coins
            self.save_data("data/balance.json", balance)
            dig_embed = discord.Embed(
                title = "Digging coins...", 
                color=discord.Color.blue()
            )
            earned_embed = discord.Embed(
                title = f"{ctx.author.display_name} went digging!", 
                description = f"You found {coins_earned} !", 
                color=discord.Color.blue()
            )
            send = await ctx.send(embed = dig_embed)
            await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
            await send.edit(embed = earned_embed)
            if gem == 1:
                gems_earned = 1
                gems = balance[user_id].get("gems")
                gems += gems_earned
                balance[user_id]["gems"] = gems
                self.save_data("data/balance.json", balance)
                await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
                gem_embed = discord.Embed(
                    title = "Wait a second...",
                    color = discord.Color.blue()
                )
                gem_embed.add_field(
                    name = "You lucky ducky!",
                    value = "You found a gem  ! Added to your balance!",
                    inline = False
                )
                await ctx.send(embed = gem_embed)
    @dig.error
    async def dig_error(self,ctx, error):
        if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
            cooldown = error.retry_after
            cooldown_dt = datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(seconds=cooldown)
            cooldown_timestamp = format_dt(cooldown_dt, style="R")
            await ctx.send(f"⏱ **| {ctx.author.display_name}:**\n> You are digging too fast!\n > Please try again in **{cooldown_timestamp}**.", delete_after=cooldown)
        elif isinstance(error, checks.NotStarted):
            need_to_register_embed = error.embed
            await ctx.send(embed=need_to_register_embed)
                
async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(Dig(bot))

What I want:
When I type .reg, the bot shall say successfully registered and my id will be put into data/registered.json file with a boolean True. And when I type .dig, since my id is in the registered file, I should be able to use the command.
The problem now:
When I type .reg, the bot does successfully register me and my discord id does get put into the data/registered.json file. But then when I type .dig, it still says I'm not registered.
I will provide a ss of what is happening.
Any help will be highly appreciated.
Register command not working

maybe you use two different data/registered.json in different folders? Maybe use /full/path/to/data/registered.json. In both functions you could also check Current Working Directory - print( os.getcwd() ). And you could also use print() to see what is in JSON file in both functions.

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debugging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

I wouldn't use JSON as a database. Instead look at something like SQLITE where you can work with columns and data structures that are easier. SQLITE is also faster than JSON which is a plus.

Are you using Replit? If you are, then that also might be why

@BlueRobin yes I am using replit, how does that affect the code?

@Kurtis I've also had the same problem and it has to do with the way JSON and replit work (I don't really know too much about this) so I'd recommend trying sqlite
